# Find the radius of four congruent circles inside a right triangle

Tags: geometry

Below is a homework assignment I'm working on, along with a correct method for solving it and what appears to be an incorrect method.  I'm hoping someone could explain what is wrong with the second method.  So —

[image: The question]

First, I'll note that my professor outlined a much easier solution in class the day after it was assigned:  Basically, divide the triangle up into pieces we know the area of and set their sum equal to the area of the whole triangle:

$$(3r)^2 + \frac{1}{2}\left[ (3r)(a - 3r) + (3r)(b - 3r) + rc \right] = \frac{1}{2}ab$$

However, I'm not much of a fan of simply filling in the blanks of other people's solutions; furthermore, I don't see why I can't solve the problem in the manner I've outlined.  The question appeared in the context of incircles, and so I figured I might use what I know about incircles to solve it.  I used the fact that, for a right triangle, $a + b = c + d$, where $d$ is the diameter of the incircle.  I started with a smaller, similar triangle and then defined the legs of the larger triangle in terms of those of the smaller.  These equations I used to solve for $r$ in terms of $a$ and $b$.

[image: Abbreviated version of my work]

But even without the correct answer (with my professor's equation, we can find $r$ in about three steps), I know that my answer is wrong, as both solutions to the quadratic equation are positive:  $ab\left[3(a+b) + \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}\right]$ is clearly positive, and since $a + b > c$, then it must be that $3(a+b) - \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}> 0$.

I've worked through this several times, on a different days and using different methods.  (For example, I've tried getting rid of the fractions on the LHS before squaring both sides, as well as squaring both sides first and then eliminating the non-cross-product terms for $a'^2$ and $b'^2$.) I always get the same answers. As far as I can tell, neither of my answers is equivalent to the correct one, though there do seem to be similarities between them.  This suggests that my error comes before all the messy algebra — in other words, when I'm still defining the problem.  Can anyone offer any insight as to where?

(Also, if I've left out any important information, I apologize.  Please let me know.  I'm trying to condense quite a few hours of work here, so...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct, but also includes an extraneous solution from the squaring process when you solve the quadratic.

The solution given by your teacher's equation (after simplifying) is

$$r=\frac{ab}{3(a+b)+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$

Rationalizing the denominator of the above, we get

$$\begin{align}\frac{ab}{3(a+b)+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}&=\frac{ab}{3(a+b)+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\times\frac{3(a+b)-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{3(a+b)-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}
\\&=\frac{3ab(a+b)-ab\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{9(a^2+2ab+b^2)-a^2-b^2}
\\&=\frac{3ab(a+b)-ab\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{2(4a^2+9ab+4b^2)}
\end{align}$$

which is one of the solutions you get.

The other solution you get comes from having a negative on the LHS of the equation before you square.

Comment: Thank you very much! Right before I posted that, I said, "Well, there's the $3(a+b)$, there's the $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, ... Let me see if I can change my answers into the correct one." I didn't even consider changing the correct answer into one of mine! (Of course, they're logically equivalent!) Thanks also for pointing out the origin of the extra solution. To clarify, since there are a number of subtractions on the LHS, do you mean the $-2r$? Or does the blame get spread around?  (Not so much that includes me, though!)

Comment: @dmk Glad to help! What I meat was that the other solution you get solves $a'+b'-2r=-\sqrt{(a')^2+(b')^2}$ instead of $a'+b'-2r=\sqrt{(a')^2+(b')^2}$ which is what you want. Both come out as solutions though because squaring gets rid of this sign difference.

Comment: Of course! Maybe it was the unknowns being spread out all over the place that made me miss that.  Who knows.  In any case, it all makes sense now :). Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I think r=(ab)/(3a+3b+c)
Connect vertices A,B,C to the center of the top right circle.  This gives you 3 triangles with area (1/2)cr , (3/2)br , (3/2)ar.